# How to add fields together automatically

Tags: django, django-models

I'm going to build up an assets management system. Every property has an unique property-code combine with department-code and type-code.

```
from django.db import models


class Department(models.Model):
    # department_code like rm01
    department_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Type(models.Model):
    # type_code like fe03
    type_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Property(models.Model):
    # property_code like rm01fe037767
    property_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

How to do that? OR is there another way to achieve the aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but not automatically.

In the normal case: when you want to add new Propery ~> User should pick other 2 model right?

```
dep_id = ?
type_id= ?
p = Property (id = dep_id+type_id, name = "blabla"...)
p.save()
And you should define the PK (default is int field, auto incre ~> to charfield) and input it by yourself
```

And normally: we don't do that...

We use: ForeignKey like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    people = models.ForeignKey(People)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks, I use `ForeignKey` to let user pick department and type. I wanted to have an unique and meaningful property-code former. But now, I think a meaningful code is useless, since I already have `ForeignKey` related with the other models. Thank you again.